# Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Intermittent Connectivity

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, atheros

So I recently installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire V3-551 laptop. I have an Atheros AR5BWB222 wireless adapter.

Everything works fine except for the wireless. I can sometimes connect to the wireless, but most of the time it will be making an attempt to connect and then enver connect.  Or it will connect, but it will only stay connected for about 10 seconds before getting disconnected from the wireless.

All the other drivers updated through System Settings>Additional Drivers are fine, even the Ethernet. Its just the problem with the wireless. I've tried a power managment setting, tried looking for additional updates, but nothing fixes my problem. Is there any solution for my particular wireless card?

Comment: Did u find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem :(